# Women wearing pants

Tags: women, clothing

I am a 14 years old girl who wants to use baggy pants but my father said that I couldn’t use any pants because that would be mutashabihat! Did Allah or the prophet said that women couldn’t wear pants?

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/5521/conditions-to-be-met-when-a-woman-wears-pants

Answer (score 1):

Salaam sister. Your father is absolutely correct. Women can wear pants but only at home not outside. Women are diamonds in Islam and these diamonds can only be uncovered in front of her mahrams. You can wear pants at home infront of your Brother and Father because they are your mahrams. But outside world is not your mahrams. Well their is no proper hadith about women wearing jeans. Many muslim girls do this but they don't know the truth. If you really want to wear pants outside then their are laws. Such as The clothes should be loose and shouldn't be tight. The private parts such as the the back side should be fully covered and visible to nobody outside because they are non mehrams. Easy way is to wear a skirt type of shirr in which parts are covered above the knees. But remember. It will be haram to reveal your private parts to anyone in the outside. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Jummah Mubarak

Assalamu alaikum sister,

First of all your father is correct.

There is a ruling that the clothes a woman wears has to meet some conditions if worn in front of any man unrelated to her, or related (ie cousin) but by law can marry that woman (non-mahram men) as not to cause any lustful desires towards her and thus protect her from such as she is precious.

These are the conditions that must be met:

The clothing should cover the whole of the body whilst hiding the body's shape and skin color (ie baggy thick clothes). It should be unattractive clothing as not to attract the non-mahram men's gaze to it (ie clothes decorated with embroidery should be avoided), it should not be perfumed. It shouldn't appear masculine. It should be different clothing to what would be associated with disbelievers and should not promote fame towards the woman wearing it.

Allah says (interpretation of the meaning):
“And tell the believing women to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts) and not to show off their adornment except only that which is apparent (like both eyes for necessity to see the way, or outer palms of hands or one eye or dress like veil, gloves, headcover, apron), and to draw their veils all over Juyoobihinna (i.e. their bodies, faces, necks and bosoms) and not to reveal their adornment except to their husbands, or their fathers, or their husband’s fathers, or their sons, or their husband’s sons, or their brothers or their brother’s sons, or their sister’s sons, or their (Muslim) women (i.e. their sisters in Islam), or the (female) slaves whom their right hands possess, or old male servants who lack vigour, or small children who have no sense of feminine sex. And let them not stamp their feet so as to reveal what they hide of their adornment. And all of you beg Allaah to forgive you all, O believers, that you may be successful” [al-Noor 24:31]

So, from this ayah of The Qu'ran we can see that we should do everything in terms of the clothes we wear to deter non-mahram men's gaze from us (ie not attract them at all to our clothes or us). The reason for no perfume and the other rules mentioned above. Now on to wearing baggy pants it 1) resembles the clothes of a man (masculine) and 2) reveals the shape of the woman's legs. However if wearing the pants under a jilbaab that doesn't show what is underneath it and is baggy and wide, concealing the body, then it is lawful to do so as it's more to do with covering and protecting the body from these lustful desires of the non-mahram men

Shaykh ‘Abd al-Razzaaq ‘Afeefi (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: If a woman wears pants and puts over them a wide garment then she will not be resembling men, so long as she wears them underneath her garments. (Shaykh ‘Abd al-Razzaaq ‘Afeefi. Page 573)

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: I think that the Muslims should not follow these fashions and kinds of clothes that come to us from here and there. Many of them are not in accordance with proper Islamic dress which involves covering the woman completely, like the short or very tight or thin clothes. That includes pants, because they show the size of a woman’s legs, as well as her stomach, waist, breasts, etc. Wearing it comes under the description given in the saheeh hadeeth: “there are two types of the people of Hell whom I have not seen: people with whips like the tails of cattle, with which they strike the people, and women who are clothed yet naked, walking with an enticing gait, with something on their heads that looks like the humps of camels, leaning to one side. They will never enter Paradise or even smell its fragrance, although its fragrance can be detected from such and such a distance.” Narrated by Muslim, 2128.

The ruling is not to wear clothing which is too long out of pride but for it to reach the ankles or even further passed the ankles.

Al-Tirmidhi (1731), al-Nasaa’i (5336), Abu Dawood (4117) and Ibn Maajah (3580) from Ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever lets his garment drag out of pride, Allaah will not look at him on the Day of Resurrection.” Umm Salamah said: “What should women do with their hems?” He said: “Let them down by a handspan.” She said: “But then their feet will be uncovered.” He said: “Then a cubit, but no more than that.” This hadeeth was classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Sunan al-Tirmidhi.

And Allah knows best

Assalamu alaikum